# How to inject parent primitive type property through child class constructor when componentscan is enabled

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a parent class Car & a sub class Axio. So, i'm trying to pass an argument through super("Axio") within child constructor to constructor parameter in the parent class which then assign the value into a property defined within the parent class. When i try executing the application in spring boot it throws me an exception stating

```
Description:

Field car in com.test.efshop.controller.HelloController required a bean of type 'com.test.efshop.Axio' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.efshop.Axio' in your configuration.
```

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this in spring boot?. My Code is as below,

// Car class

```
package com.test.efshop;

public class Car {

private String carName;

public String getCarName() {
    return carName;
}

public void setCarName(String carName) {
    this.carName = carName;
}

public Car(String carName) {
    this.carName = carName;
}

public String print() {
    return "Car name is : "+carName;    
}
}
```

//sub class of car class which is Axio

```
  package com.test.efshop;

    public class Axio extends Car{

    public Axio() {
        super("Axio");
    }   
    }
```

//main method

```
package com.test.efshop;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

//controller class

```
package com.test.efshop.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.test.efshop.Axio;
import com.test.efshop.Engine;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private Axio car;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public ModelAndView print() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
    //This is the method which i used to return the value of Car class
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello2")
    @ResponseBody
    public String print2() {
        return car.print();
    }


}
```

Comment: is your Axio car a spring bean? I mean does it have `@Component` or `@Service` annotation?

Comment: Since i'm using spring boot and these classes are within the same package where main application class is located, i think it is not necessarily needed to have these classes annotated with @Component, right?. Please correct me if i wrong.

Comment: even though these classes are annotated with @Component yet the application does not work as expected

Comment: Without one of the Spring annotations, it doesnt get scanned . It has to be there. And also these  classes should be in spring's component scan path

Comment: Yes, I've tried annotating these classes as well but does not work. By the way, if you could, would please run a test & print back me the result if possible?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pvpkiran commented, you can't `@Autowire` a class if it's not a Spring bean.

Option a) you convert the `Axio` class into a service or component.

```
@Component
public class Axio extends Car {
    public Axio() {
        super("Axio");
    }   
}
```

Option b) you define a bean of type `Axio`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Axio myAxioBean() {
        return new Axio();
    }

}
```

Comment: Great!!, We came closer! This works fine when declaring the Axio class a spring beans within the spring main application. But my question is why does it still need to declare as a bean or either @Component as spring boot  creates bean itself for these classes?. e.g. Car class in our application.

Comment: @FarhanDulip Spring does **not** create a bean for a class unless you add `@Component` (or similar) or manually instantiate it with `@Bean`.

Comment: Are you sure even though it is in spring boot? Please Apologize.

Comment: @FarhanDulip I think you meant "please explain"? Yes, I am sure. It would be a mess if Spring picked up any class and began creating random beans without asking.

Comment: You are correct @ESala if it is not autowired so you have to declare the bean or should be annotated. By the way thanks for helping out dude. Keep up the great work...Cheers!!!!